# Установить начальный url vue-router

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

Так уж случилось, что входная точка приложения находится не по пути, например, `test.com/`, а по пути `test.com/aaa/`.

Когда в настройках роутера я указываю начальный путь `/`, то vue определяет стартовый `url` как `test.com/aaa#` и все дальнейшие переходы осуществялет основываясь на этом `test.com/aaa#`. Например, при попадании на страницу `zzz` `url` выглядит так - `test.com/aaa#/zzz`, а я хочу, чтобы он выглядел `test.com#/zzz`.  Ну и соответственно стартовый `url` был доменом и выглядел вот так `test.com#`. Как это настроить?

```
export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',  //url выглядит так test.com/aaa/#
      name: 'aaa',
      component: aaa,
    },
    {
      path: '/zzz',
      name: 'zzz',
      component: zzz,
    },
  ],
});
```

П.С.: если указываю стартовый путь как

```
{
          path: '/aaa', 
          name: 'aaa',
          component: aaa,
        },
```

то компонент вообще не загружается

Comment: тут роутинг не поможет, тебе приложение на твоем вебсервере надо настраивать как  дефолтный сайт по нужному адресу

Comment: @Konst, тоже так думаю, но вдруг есть решения другие.  Возможно тут помогут опции констурктора... https://router.vuejs.org/ru/api/#base, но я не знаю как их подключить